# Hadoop and multiple clusters

Tags: hadoop

Aside from administrative effort, is there any definitive reason not to create multiple hadoop clusters for handling different big data content?

For example a PCI hadoop cluster, a security cluster and an application logging cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, big one: better resource utilization.

Comment: That's not really a definitive reason however. Would there be a larger pool of resources on the whole by not making multiple clusters, sure. But there are very real reasons for separating them for example PCI certification of the environment and data that needs access to it restricted to only accessed by a security group which can potentially justify the separation of the clusters. Can you think of any other reasons?

Comment: As I'm not seeing any added answers I'm accepting this one as a valid point although not a complete answer to the question.

Comment: So ascetic answer is a consequence of the form of a question. It is far more easy to find "why we need separate clusters", then "why we need one cluster". I think, one big cluster actually is harder to administrate. It is too many different factors, which can bring big cluster down.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of one cluster for all content is the ability to find patterns across all the data.  Patterns in application usage may apply to security, particularly in identification theft.

A user has a signature behavior with each application. When that behavior changes, are there associated anomalies in your security data?

If you see the data as distinct, you will never find multichannel patterns.  Pretend you don't know what you are looking for, and perhaps you will start to see the need to have the data in one place.